# Add a point on a spplot in R

Tags: r, point, coordinates, sp

I have to add a point on a existing `spplot` in R. I need it only for a visual purpose. I have the coordinates of the point, but I don't know how to change the code in order to add the point.

This is the code of the `spplot`:

```
spplot(pioggiaTP[1])
```

And this is the map obtained by running the command:
[image: spplot]

The coordinates of the point are X=720731,8704 and Y=4861300,795 in the reference system WGS 84 / UTM zone 32N EPSG:32632, the same system of the plot.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 6):

`spplot` returns a [lattice](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lattice/index.html) plot of class "trellis". You can use the `layer` function from the `latticeExtra` package to update this object.

Example:

```
library("sp")
library("latticeExtra")

data(meuse)
data(meuse.grid)

coordinates(meuse.grid) <- ~x+y
proj4string(meuse.grid) <- CRS("+init=epsg:28992")

p <- spplot(meuse.grid, "dist")
print(p)
```

[image: spplot]

```
p + layer(panel.points(x, y, col="green", pch=19), data=meuse)
```

[image: spplot update]

Answer (score 4):

Another option would be to make use of the 'sp.layout' argument that comes with `spplot`. Note that in contrast to the approach suggested by @rcs, you are required to supply an 'sp' object (which you might have already available since you are working with `spplot`). Using the 'meuse.grid' dataset, your code could roughly look as follows.

```
## sample point
test <- data.frame(x = 180000, y = 331500)
coordinates(test) <- ~ x + y
proj4string(test) <- "+init=epsg:28992"

## display gridded data including sample point
spplot(meuse.grid, "dist", scales = list(draw = TRUE),
       sp.layout = list("sp.points", test, pch = 16, cex = 2, col = "black"))
```

[image: sp.layout]